# spherical bessel function derivative

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions

i want to evaluate differentiation of spherical Bessel function at r = 0 but i am not able to get a value for it. Any kind of help is appreciated

```
w = Table[i, {i, 1, 8}];
p = Table[i, {i, 1, 100}];

L = 50;
as = Table[N[BesselJZero[3/2, i]], {i, Length[p]}]; 
urS = Table[
   Sum[con[[i]]*(as[[n]] r)/L*SphericalBesselJ[1, (as[[n]] r)/L], {n, 
     Length[p]}], {i, Length[w]}];
RS1[r_] = urS[[1]]/r
ur0[r_] := Abs[D[RS1[r], r]]^2
Limit[ur0[r], r -> 0]
```

'as' are the zeroes of spherical bessel function. urS is sum of these sph bessel function. con[[i]] is a list of constants length[w]. i want to then find radial function which is defined by RS1 (upto RS8 since their are 8 functions inside urS). I have only considered RS1 here. Find a value for ur0 at r =0.  What am i doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your code is somwhat unclear. What exactly do you want to do?

And it seems that what you want does not exist :

```
fsb = D[SphericalBesselJ[n, x], x]
fsbL = Limit[fsb, x -> 0]
(fsbL /. n -> # // N) & /@ Range[0, 5]
```

Comment: I have edited my question. let me know if any part is not clear to you

Comment: as are the zeros of BesselJ and not of SphericalBesselJ. I still don not know what you want to do.

Comment: `fsb = D[SphericalBesselJ[#, x], x] & /@ Range[0, 5]; Limit[#, x -> 0] & /@ fsb` evaluates to `{0, 1/3, 0, 0, 0, 0}`